# Select all points that are within a 100 metre radius of a POINT()

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial

I have a table in a database with over a million geospatial points that we'll call **'flags'**. I also have a feed of live **'vehicles'** which report their latitude and longitude positions.

Every time a vehicle's position comes through I need to run code that does this:

Select all **flags** that are within a 100 metre radius of this vehicle's position.

Is this possible with SQL? If so how could I go about doing it?

Comment: wasnt my downvote but you should show what you have already tried to do

Comment: @AnthonyBlake I'd love to but I can't show what I've already tried to do if I don't know where to start D: (hence why I asked the question)

Comment: Are you using MySQL's [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/spatial-extensions.html)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17032718.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks very much! That looks very useful. Just need to update MySQL and I'll check it out.

Comment: @eggyal Perhaps you could answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168380/use-mysql-spatial-extensions-to-check-if-table-of-points-are-inside-circle

Answer (score 1):

Should be doable using the formula

```
(x-center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 < radius^2
```

You have all the component parts to do

```
SELECT foo
  FROM point p
 WHERE (((p.x - vehicle.x) * (p.x - vehicle.x)) + ((p.y - vehicle.y) * (p.y - vehicle.y))) < 1000
```

Or somethign like that, I've taken a few syntax punts

Comment: This does not take advantage of MySQL's spatial extensions, nor is it geodesic (Pythagoras' theorem only works in Euclidean geometry).

Comment: The distance of 100 meters is small enough that you can use an approximation (vs. Haversine formulae). But the responder's method is Pythagoras' theorem which is fine at the equator but will grow in error as you move toward the poles (due to curvature in longitude lines).

I would recommend using Pythagoras' theorem on an equilateral projection which approximates the curvature along the longitude lines. See http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

Check these resources:

1. [Selecting points within a bounding circle](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html) -- gives detailed information about optimal solution: select rectangular area and then filter out points that do not fall into the circle inside that square;
2. [Select coordinates which fall within a radius of a central point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783684/select-coordinates-which-fall-within-a-radius-of-a-central-point) -- similar question on stackoverflow.