# java script react native maps find markers close to a location using local db

Tags: mysql, geolocation, maps, markers

I have an application that has a bunch or latitudes and longitudes of restaurants stored in a database,

I need to load map markers based where the map is currently focused. for example if the map is focused on a city i need to load markers only within the city/ radius.

i am using `react-native-maps` for the map rendering and the backend is nodejs.

Comment: What is your database? Some databases (eg PostgreSQL) have good support for geo queries.

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: Fair enough. If you are able to index the restaurant lat/longs in the database yourself, I suggest following something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799118/mysql-find-points-within-radius-from-database. By the way, this question isn't really about react-native.

Comment: ok thanks - @mrblewog