# Call a function in MySQL to filter out the restaurants which are near to the user's current location

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

### What's Needed?

I want to get all the restaurants that are near the user's current location *(10KM in range)*.

### Description

I have a users table `user(Id, Name, Address)`, here the address is a `lat, long` string. e.g. `20,21`.

2nd table is `restaurant(Id, Name, Address)`, and the format for address is the same as above.

On the front-end I get the current location of the user, and send to the API, and in the API I have a function calling below query from MySQL:

```ts
const getAllRestaurants = async (currentAddress: string): Promise<Array<Restaurant>> => {
  // query restaurants (using typeorm which will generate something like this)
  const rests = "SELECT * FROM restaurant LIMIT 0, 10";

  const restsToReturn = [];

  // got the restaurants, now filter on based of address
  for (const rest of rests) {
    // call "isRestaurantInRange" which will return true if the restaurant is user's range
    if (isRestaurantInRange(rest.Address, currentAddress)) {
      restsToReturn.push(rest);
    }
  }

  return restsToReturn;
}
```

### Drawbacks:

- It's SLOW.
- The pagination doesn't work as expected, because if 2 out of 10 are in the user's range then we have to manually load up the next data and check the same condition until it reaches 10.
- It's a DIRTY way to approach it.

### What I am expecting:

- Can `isRestaurantInRange` saved in database (MySQL)? So that when I request the function runs on the database level and return the expected results, without manually filtering it? I am not a MySQL expert, but stored procedure will **NOT** work as far as I know. Although, there's a caveat with this approach. i.e. I can't call Google Maps Distance API to have exact distance between two points, so need a solution which have google API working.
- If you know a TypeORM based solution, it would also be acceptable.

Comment: You should filter results in mysql and not your client, also dont select all at once.

Comment: That's the question, HOW TO FILTER ON MYSQL? Like can you run the filter function which I am running in MySQL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799118/mysql-find-points-within-radius-from-database . You can also use mysqls `CREATE FUNCTION` to create callable functions in your database.

Comment: But what if I want to call the google's API to have a exact distance between two points?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find nearest latitude/longitude with an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/find-nearest-latitude-longitude-with-an-sql-query)

Comment: NO! Same question above: "What about if I need to use Google API"?

Comment: Well, if it was me I'd start with the sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it was suggested to stick with MySQL implementation, which of course doesn't give accurate result. Anyways, I am using following query to get it:

```mysql
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(31.4630941 74.3215482)', 4326 ),
                   ST_GeomFromText('POINT(31.4780632 74.3125699)', 4326 ),
                  'kilometre') AS distance;
```

Used [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=59.3293371N%2013.4877472W%20to%2059.3225525N%2013.4619422W%20in%20km) link to verify that the MySQL function gives correct STRAIGHT distance between two points.

[This](https://mysqlserverteam.com/spatial-reference-systems-in-mysql-8-0/) is a great article about spatial data in MySQL. Quoting:

> These are two of the most used SRSs. SRID 4326 is GPS coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a SPATIAL index with InnoDB, you need MySQL 5.7.6 (or newer) to also get `SP_Distance_Sphere()`.

Do store the actual POINTs in the table; that is, don't compute them on the fly since that is likely to prevent the use of the index.

For other tips, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

There may be a disadvantage in splitting into 2 tables.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.